Show that $\frac{xy}{(x+y)(1+x)(1+y)} \leq \frac{1}{8}$ for $x, y > 0$
How could I show that
$$
\forall \: x,y >0, \frac{xy}{(x+y)(1+x)(1+y)} \leq \frac{1}{8} \quad ?
$$
My first attempt was to study the critical points of $$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(x+y)(1+x)(1+y)}.$$ If we restrict ourselves to $x,y >0$, we find a unique critical point $(1,1)$ (and $f(1,1)=\frac{1}{8}$). But the Hessian matrix is degenerated at this point... thus we cannot use the usual criterion with $r, s, t$...
I guess there should be trick, but I don't see which one...

I think there is a solution without any difficult optimization trick. I will simply use A.M.-G.M. inequality of two variables.

First note, given $x,y >0$, your inequality can be rearranged to look like $8xy \leq ((x+y)(1+x)(1+y)$, which in turn can be simplified to $$6xy \leq x+y+x^2+y^2+x^2y+xy^2.$$ So if we can show this last inequality then we are done.

By A.M. - G.M. inequality we have $x^2+y^2 \geq 2xy$.

By A.M. - G.M. inequality we have $x+y \geq 2\sqrt{xy}$.

By A.M. - G.M. inequality we have $x^2y+xy^2 \geq 2x^{3/2}y^{3/2}$.

By A.M. - G.M. inequality we have $x^{3/2}y^{3/2} + \sqrt{xy} \geq 2xy$.


Combining steps 2.-5., gives us the desired inequality of step 1.

Side note: Seems easier to 1/ Just do all 6 terms at once $x+y+x^2+y^2+x^2y+xy^2 \geq 6\sqrt[6]{x^6y^6}$, or 2/ If we want to split, pair them up as:$x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy, x+xy^2 \geq 2xy, y+x^2y\geq 2xy$.

Using the inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean:
$$
 xy = \sqrt{\mathstrut x\cdot y}  \cdot \sqrt{\mathstrut 1 \cdot x}  \cdot \sqrt{\mathstrut 1 \cdot y} 
\le \frac{x+y}{2} \cdot \frac{1+x}{2}\cdot \frac{1+y}{2} \, .
$$
Equality holds if and only if $x=y=1$.
